# Test for substring in posix shell .sh script (NOT bash)

Tags: shell-script, shell

I use an .sh script to read the installed firmware of a controller and to compare it with the available firmware (and update on the controller if needed).

To make sure the readout works I want to test the response string for the substring "ERROR" (created by the separate script reading from the controller).

I tried multiple ways to test for the substring, but nothing worked until now. Most sources I found use bash, complicating the search.

EDIT: "full" relevant code

```
MCU_VER=$($PRG)
echo "SubMCU Firmware version readout:" >> /tmp/version_test_log.txt
echo $MCU_VER >> /tmp/version_test_log.txt
case "$MCU_VER" in
    *"ERROR"*)
        echo "Error" >> /tmp/version_test_log.txt
        FW_READ=0;;
    *)
        echo "Success" >> /tmp/version_test_log.txt
        FW_READ=1;;
esac
let LOOP_CNT=LOOP_CNT+1
echo "Loop count:" >> /tmp/version_test_log.txt
echo $LOOP_CNT >> /tmp/version_test_log.txt
echo "Readout state:" >> /tmp/version_test_log.txt
echo $FW_READ >> /tmp/version_test_log.txt
```

The logfile looks like this:

```
SubMCU Firmware version readout:
ERROR: Failed to init GPIO output pin 77
Success
Loop count:
1
Readout state:
1
```

EDITEDIT: The code now works. The solution is the case construct.

Comment: Note that `[[ ]]` isn't valid for sh, that's a bash and other modern shell thing. What is your `/bin/sh`? Is it `dash`? Is it `bash` symlinked as `sh`? What is the output of `ls -l /bin/sh` or `sh --version`? It doesn't really matter much since Gilles' answer will work on any of them, but it might be relevant.

Comment: Note that blindly writing to files with fixed names in world-writable directories such as `/tmp` is a big security no-no.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas the decision to write our logfiles to /tmp was not made by me and since the system is not connected to a network i guess it's fine

Comment: @Serakis "Security no-no" in this case could also mean "Has the potential to overwrite other files". It has nothing to do with being connected to any network.

Comment: FYI, `let` is a ksh builtin command, not a POSIX sh command. The POSIX sh equivalent would be `LOOP_CNT=$(( LOOP_CNT + 1 ))`

Comment: Is it possible that the "ERROR" being output by your `$PRG` contains other characters, e.g. it might be _ backspace E _ backspace R _ backspace R _ backspace O _ backspace R in an attempt to underline the word. Can you add a dump of the logfile, using `hd` or `od -c` to the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a Bourne/POSIX shell, there's no built-in way to do a substring check using conditionals (`[ … ]`), but there is one using a `case` statement.

```
case "$MCU_VAR" in
  *"ERROR"*)
    echo "Error" >> /tmp/version_test_log.txt
    FW_READ=0;;
  *)
    echo "Success" >> /tmp/version_test_log.txt
    FW_READ=1;;
esac
```

This is faster than calling `grep`, and also more robust with respect to special characters which `echo` or `grep` could mangle. `case "$foo" in *"$bar"*) …` tests whether the value of `foo` contains the value of `bar` as a substring, and that works for all strings, even if they contain newlines, backslashes, asterisks, etc.

Comment: Strictly speaking, with POSIX shells (the Bourne shell is not in use any longer), you can do `[ "${haystack#*needle}" != "$haystack" ]` but that has no advantage whatsoever over using a `case` construct.

Comment: Tried this, still not working. Value for MCU_VAR was "ERROR: Failed to init GPIO output pin 77" but the case construct jumped to the "Success" case.

Comment: @Serakis, try running your script with `sh -x`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas still not working :(

Comment: @Serakis, sh -x is to print some debug output explaining why it's not working for you. Most likely you have a typo in your code or the variable doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas no debug information was printed to the terminal during execution

Comment: @Serakis That's definitely surprising. The script will output tracing information when you run it with `sh -x`. Your comment only shows that you are either not running the script with `sh -x`, or that you are ignoring the error stream from the script. Note that a cron job will _mail_ you any output of a script that you don't explicitly write to a file. A cron jab would never output anything to any terminal.

Comment: @Kusalananda running the script with sh -x shows exactly the same as in the logfile:
# sh -x script.sh 
+ MCU_VER='ERROR: Timeout'
+ echo 'SubMCU Firmware version readout:'
+ echo ERROR: Timeout
+ echo Success
+ FW_READ=1

Comment: @Serakis You have both `MCU_VER` and `MCU_VAR`. Pick one. Use `set -u` to ensure that using unset variables lead to an error, rather than defaulting to empty.

Comment: @Serakis can you please edit your question and post the _exact_ output of running the script with `sh -x` (it's very hard to read and easy to miss in the comments). We also need to be sure of which variable contains what.

Comment: This is the solution. Thanks @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' for the solution. It only did not work at first because i had a typo in it.

Answer (score 0):

What you need:

```
if printf '%s\n' "$MCU_VAR" | grep -q "ERROR"; then
    printf '%s\n' "Error" >> /tmp/version_test_log.txt
    FW_READ=0
else
    printf '%s\n' "Success" >> /tmp/version_test_log.txt
    FW_READ=1
fi
```

Don't use `[[ ]]` aka *`ksh/bash/zsh/...` tests* in `POSIX` shell.

Comment: Just tested it. The String in MCU_VAR is "ERROR: Comm. timeout of SubMCU"
Yet the if case jumps to else and prints "Success" to my log file.

Comment: @Serakis Note that you are appending to the output file, so any "Success" string in there could come from an earlier run of the code when you variable did not contain the "ERROR" substring.

Comment: Same applies for the other Gilles's answer, you don't add the same disclaimer as comment?

Comment: @Kusalananda the script runs during boot, the log is in the /tmp so new log file every attempt.

Comment: `[[...]]` is from ksh from the early 80s, not bash (though it is now supported by bash and a few other shells as well).

Comment: @Serakis I think it's safe to say that you do not know what your `MCU_VAR` contains; in other words, it does not contain what you believe it does. You have either a typo in this script or in whatever it is that generates or stores your variable's value, or you have misunderstood the system you  are trying to interface.  There is nothing in your question that shows how you populate your variable, or what the output of this script is when you run it under `sh -x`.

Comment: @GillesQuénot your updated code doesn't work on my system either...